# Datastage job to read an empty file

Tags: datastage

What changes should I make in a datastage job in order to run a job successfully even with a empty input file. I have a job that reads a file as an input and undergo into some transformations and will give an end file. I want to make the job run even if the source file contains zero records. Do I need to make changes in sequence job or parallel job? Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no reason why a job should not end successfully if no data is processed. Why do you think it will return an error? If you get one describe the situation.

Comment: I am getting an error while running the sequence job but not parallel. I do think that the error is because there is failure in one of the parallel jobs, but my concern is will the sequence job also run with an empty file without failure? Do I need to write in the trigger like it shouldn't fail? This my trigger Int(Trim(Field(Field(abc.$CommandOutput,@FM,1,1),'/',1,1)))  > 1 and I have used wc -l command. Is it enough or do I need to add anything?

Comment: Jobs will run successfully even no data is processes - this a general rule. WIthout details on what you try to achive it is hard to help. What is the trigger for?

Comment: Yes, the Job ran successfully one thing I have done is I have changed the missing column mode to continue instead of reject in parallel job. Thanks for the information Michael

Comment: Well you have no information about any stage that rejects in your question. If my answer satisfies your needs please vote for it